# Error while reading from a file in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am new to Unix and need help with a certain code.
My if condition acts weird.

Suppose my data is as follows -

```
name1 place1 date1
name2 place2 date2
name3 place3 date3
name4 place4 date4
name5 place5 date5
```

This is what I had originally done -

```
SRC_PATH="/app/Informatica9.5.1/server/infa_shared/0149icadd/SrcFiles"
rm -f temp_con_total
cat $SRC_PATH/Control_Total.txt > temp_con_total
echo $SRC_PATH
i=0
while read line 
do
echo $line
if [[[ $i -ge 0 ]]];
then
    file_name=`echo -e $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
    file_size=`echo -e $line | cut -d ' ' -f 3`
    file_size=$(( $file_size ))

    actual_size=`cat $SRC_PATH/$file_name | wc -l`
    actual_size=`echo -e $actual_size | cut  -d ' ' -f 1`
    actual_size=$(( $actual_size - 1 ))

    echo $file_name
    echo $file_size
    echo $actual_size
fi  
i=$(( i + 1 ))
done < temp_con_total
```

in this case, it gave me only first 2 records.

Later, I removed one set of brackets from if condition -

```
if [ $i -ge 0 ];
```

in this case, it gave me only the first row.
later i put three brackets, as follows -

```
if [[[ $i -ge 0 ]]];
```

now, it did give me all rows but after each row it also gave me error as follows:

```
name1 place1 date1
loop.sh[10]: [[[: not found [No such file or directory]
name2 place2 date2
loop.sh[10]: [[[: not found [No such file or directory]
name3 place3 date3
loop.sh[10]: [[[: not found [No such file or directory]
name4 place4 date4
loop.sh[10]: [[[: not found [No such file or directory]
name5 place5 date5
loop.sh[10]: [[[: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Can someone please help me with this? Why is this happening?
loop.sh is the name of my script

What I need as output is, all rows in the file as follows- 
    name1 place1 date1
    name2 place2 date2
    name3 place3 date3
    name4 place4 date4
    name5 place5 date5

I want to know why is there an error after it prints each row? `loop.sh[10]: [[[: not found [No such file or directory]`

And how does the number of brackets affect the code?

Comment: I assume we just have to guess what `$i` is (it seems there's a for-loop missing somewhere), what `$line` is, and what you actually expect as output?

Comment: sorry. There's a while loop before that.

Comment: Can you update this question with a complete code example?

Comment: I have added the complete code.

Comment: please fix you copy/paste. it's still wrong.

Comment: sorry. It was there. Got concatenated with the previous statement. This is the code, finally.

Comment: If I remove all the "fluff" and just execute your script with a while loop and an if-statement, I consistently enter the "True" side of the if-branch. One or two brackets doesn't matter. So I'm afraid I can't really reproduce your problem.

Comment: Okay. No issues.
Would you have any idea, why there's an error line after each row print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash does not use square brackets. Not as brackets anyway. It looks like it does, but it doesn't.

There is a command called `[` (that's its name, an opening bracket) that is much the same as the `test` command. That command takes a series of command line parameters, just like any other command, and it expects that the last parameter will be a closing bracket, `]`, but no actual bracket processing is done. This is why you always follow the closing bracket with a semi-colon, `;`, to finish the command. If you look in `/bin` (or `/usr/bin`?) you'll see that `/bin/[` exists as a file.

Likewise, there's another command called `[[` (again, that's its name, two opening brackets together). This is the same idea as the `[` command, but has slightly different features. This one doesn't usually have a file in `/bin`.

Both commands are implemented as bash builtins, for efficiency in the case of `[` and because `[[` has to be, I think, but that doesn't affect the syntax.

There is no command named `[[[`, hence "No such file or directory".

---

As for your script, the `if` is completely pointless because you test if `$i` is greater than, or equal to zero when there's no way it can't be. I think this should do what you want:

```
SRC_PATH="/app/Informatica9.5.1/server/infa_shared/0149icadd/SrcFiles"
rm -f temp_con_total
cp $SRC_PATH/Control_Total.txt temp_con_total
echo $SRC_PATH
while read line 
do
    echo $line
    file_name=`echo -e $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
    file_size=`echo -e $line | cut -d ' ' -f 3`

    actual_size=`cat $SRC_PATH/$file_name | wc -l | cut  -d ' ' -f 1`
    (( actual_size-- ))

    echo $file_name
    echo $file_size
    echo $actual_size
done < temp_con_total
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That was really informative.

And yes, it solved the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Here's something that I just noticed, 
`(( actual_size-- ))` should decrease the value of `actual_size` by `1` but its giving me a value that's decremented by 2.
When I removed that statement, that is without performing any `(( actual_size-- ))` , it gave me a value that's decremented by `1`.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Without that I'd expect `actual_size` to be the exact number returned by `wc -l`.

Comment: Yes, that should happen but when I execute the script, the value of `actual_size` that I get is decremented by 1.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` at the top, temporarily. That ought to shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: xtrace [32] -> 0< temp_con_total
xtrace [7] -> read line
xtrace [11] -> echo JIM a1.txt $'4\r'
JIM a1.txt 4
xtrace [12] -> echo -e JIM a1.txt $'4\r'
xtrace [12] -> cut -d ' ' -f 2
xtrace [12] -> file_name=a1.txt
xtrace [13] -> echo -e JIM a1.txt $'4\r'
xtrace [13] -> cut -d ' ' -f 3
xtrace [13] -> file_size=$'4\r'
xtrace [15] -> cat /app/Informatica9.5.1/server/infa_shared/0149icadd/0149icadd_root/shell/vivek/a1.txt
xtrace [15] -> wc -l
xtrace [15] -> actual_size=3
xtrace [16] -> actual_size=2
xtrace [18] -> echo a1.txt
a1.txt
xtrace [19] -> echo $'4\r'
4
xtrace [20] -> echo 2
2

Comment: Sorry about that. Basically, its calculating actual_size wrong. For a file with `file_size` 4, it calculated `actual_count` as `3` and then decremented it again by -1 to give `2`